# What is wrong with this code for the classic 'Subset Sum' problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

*Problem Statement: Given a list of integers (nums) and an integer x, check if some (possibly all) elements from the list, when added, give x.*

Solution:

```
int dp[20001];
int recurse(vector<int>& nums, int x, int i) {
        
    if (x == 0)
        return 1;
        
    if (i < 0 or x < 0)
        return 0;
        
    if (dp[x] != -1)
        return dp[x];
        
    return dp[x] = recurse(nums, x - nums[i], i - 1) or recurse(nums, x, i - 1);
}
bool canPartition(vector<int>& nums, int x) {
        
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof dp);
    return recurse(nums, x, nums.size() - 1);
}
```

Problem is with the last line. If I change the order of recursions, i.e., recurse(nums, x, i - 1) first and then recurse(nums, x - nums[i], i - 1), I get wrong result.
e.g., [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> False

I'm guessing it has something to do with apparently wrong values being put in dp array which then returns the same when looked up again. But please clarify further. Not able to see through it clearly.

PS: All elements of dp array are -1 initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dp` array depends only on the value of `x`. But it should depend on both `x` and `i`.

As an example:

Suppose nums = [1, 2, 3, 13] and x=13.

Then `recurse(nums, 13, 3)` should return 1, but `recurse(nums, 13, 2)` should return 0. With your code, if you called `recurse(nums, 13, 2)` first then `dp[13]` would be assigned an incorrect result. If you had two separate entries `dp[13][3]` and `dp[13][2]` then there would be no issue.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1r1a8ui

as you can see, it gives the desired result

Comment: @SaptarshiGanguly Yes, but if you called `recurse(nums, 13, 2)` followed by `recurse(nums, 13, 3)` then you'd get incorrect results.